# Feynman Lectures on Physics Vol-I 32-3 Radiation damping. How does this classical result relate to QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, scattering, semiclassical, photon-emission

The following is from https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_32.html#Ch32-S3

> Now let us actually calculate the Q of an atom that is emitting light—let us say a sodium atom. For a sodium atom, the wavelength is roughly 6000 angstroms, in the yellow part of the visible spectrum, and this is a typical wavelength. Thus
> \begin{equation}
> Q=\frac{3\lambda}{4\pi r_0}\approx 5\times10^7,
> \end{equation}
> so the Q of an atom is of the order $10^8$. This means that an atomic oscillator will oscillate for $10^8$ radians or about $10^7$ oscillations, before its energy falls by a factor $1/e$.

The above statement seems to have no correlation to the concept of photon emission by an atom.  Is it just a presentation of classical theory for the sake of the exercise, or does it fit into quantum theory?  If it does have a QM interpretation, what would that be?